# How to generate signed apk in react native 0.60-RC

Tags: android, react-native

Can't generate signed apk that can be installed directly on device without connecting to the server.The command given in new documentation is

```
   cd android
   $ ./gradlew bundleRelease
```

which will generate .aab file and app-debug.apk only.

can I use the below command to generate apk in react native 0.60-RC? Can't find that command in their updated document.

```
 $ ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.aab` is a bundle file which can replace release `.apk`, anw, you can open Android Studio, build a release APK follow `Build/Generate Signed Bundle(s)/ APK` and tick on APK checkbox

**UPDATE**
`.aab` cannot install directly, but if you want to install the app on a real device without a server (node), you can using below way

**Step 1:**

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

**Step 2:**

```
cd android
$ ./gradlew assembleDebug
```

now the debug APK file includes the bundle server, so you can install it on your real device independently.

Comment: can I install .aab file on real device?

Comment: `Step 1 throws error`:

Loading dependency graph, done. Loading dependency graph...info Writing bundle output to:, android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle error ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle'. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Comment: This bundle command is not good advice. If you generate the assets in your src dir you will get duplicate resource errors later. I learned this the hard way! for gradle way to bundle or `mkdir -p android/app/build/generated/assets/react/release/ && mkdir -p android/app/build/generated/res/react/release && node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/build/generated/assets/react/release/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/build/generated/res/react/release`